# No autocompletion when using a std::unordered_map::find

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have some piece of code that looks like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> map;
auto result = map.find("key i'm looking for");
```

when I try to use result in this fashion:

```
result->second->Bar()
```

my IDE can't autocomplete and tells me  "No suggestions for members of auto0"

Is my syntax wrong or is it a shortcoming of the API?

EDIT: As it was pointed out, it would probably be a problem with my IDE. If anyone else can confirm this, I will report the issue on their issue tracker. I'm using CLion build CL 140.1740.3 
Thank you

EDIT2: So I made a ticket. If anyone with the same problem reads this, here is the link to the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2278

Comment: It's a shortcoming of your IDE - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a45223eae3635d7e

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you could try closing the solution, deleting the `SOLUTIONNAME.sdf` file and then opening the solution again, to force the IntelliSense to refresh.

Comment: I'm using CLion, it does make sense that it would be a shortcoming of the IDE considering it's not yet a final release.

Comment: I see this often on people learning programming: they rely on autocomplete or real-time error highlight too much. So many times I've seen them confused and freeze because the syntax highlighter was RED for a correct piece of code. Sometimes you just have to wait for it to catch-up with the text update, sometimes it just doesn't perform a deep analysis, sometimes not all compiler features have been implemented in autocomplete. **Autocomplete doesn't replace compiling**. If it compiles then it's good. If it doesn't compile then it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Your auto complete is not working correctly for some reason.